# Listening Multiple files from S3 bucket using apache camel

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-camel

I am listening the multiple files from s3 bucket using apache camel with prefix
aws-s3://%s?amazonS3Client=#%s&prefix=eels-initialfeed
list of files such as eels-initialfeed-md,eels-initialfeed-od, etc..
i just want to know that, is it possible to get the file name the one app is listening from exchange object ? / is there any other way to get the file name ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help us help you, please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

In exhange there is a header called CamelFileName. [Info](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html)

Comment: yeah. thanks. i have got this information from exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelAwsS3Key")